# How to do lambda operations with stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

As for now I am doing :

```
Map<Integer, Item> itemList = getItems(input);

Iterator<Item> ItemIterator = input.getItems().iterator();

List<Item> updatedItems = Lists.newLinkedList();

for (int i = MIN; i <= input.getInputReq().getList().size(); i++) {
    Item item = itemList.get(i);
    if (item != null) {
        item.setFlag(false);
        item.setId(getId());
        updatedItems.add(item);
        itemList.remove(i);
    } else {
        if (ItemIterator.hasNext()) {
            updatedItems.add(ItemIterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any efficient way I could do this with Streams and lambda in java8 ?

Comment: with lambda and stream? sure

Comment: You are accessing the unknown contents of your `input ` in so many ways that it is (nearly) impossible for someone who doesn't know the context to help you find a neat solution.

Comment: @RobinTopper Sorry for making my question unclear. The input is an object with flag (boolean) and Id (String)

Answer (score 1):

This an answer (not sure it is correct) but almost as obscure as your question:

```
int size = input.getInputReq().getList();
List<Item> updatedItems = IntStream.range(0, size)
           .mapToObj(i -> itemList.get(i) )
           .map(e -> 
           {
             return Optional.of(e).map(i -> {
                i.setFlag(false);
                i.setId(getId());
                return i;
             }).orElse(ItemIterator.next());
           }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The issue is I need to keep track of 2 numbers. My List starts from 0 but my map starts from 1.

Comment: @user3407267 fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

I would in your case write a separate method which does the updating and puts the items in the updatedItems-collection:

```
private void updateItemsAndPutThemInList(Item item){
    item.setFlag(false);
    setId(getId());
    updatedItems.add(item);
}
```

And then process them with the following code:

```
input.getItems().stream().filter(i -> i != null).forEach(i -> updateItemsAndPutThemInList(i));
```

Depending on the purpose of your code, you could specify the list into which the updated items have to be put as an argument for the private method, whose signature would then be:

```
private void updateItemsAndPutThemInList(Item item, List<Item> updatedItems)
```

and which requires the forEach-method to get this a reference (which must be effectively final!) to this list.

Comment: But the issue is I need to keep track of 2 integers. 1 - index of list and 2 - min  1 to size